# How to access hidden file upload field with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have such HTML:

[image]

```
upload_input = $driver.find_element(:id, "//input[@name = 'coupon_file']")
$driver.execute_script "$('input').show();"
upload_input.send_keys file
```

I'm trying to upload a file but get the error:

> no such element: Unable to locate element

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". Don't use a link to point to information used to help define or demonstrate the problem. Links rot then break, resulting in questions that make no sense. Instead, reduce the input the bare minimum then add it to your question, formatted appropriately.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352369/uploading-files-using-ruby-selenium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> upload_input = $driver.find_element(:id, "//input[@name = 'coupon_file']")

Actually you're doing incorrect. **You're trying to locate upload element using `xpath` syntax but mentioned `id` locator which is incorrect**. It should be as below :-

```
upload_input = $driver.find_element(:xpath, "//input[@name = 'coupon_file']")
upload_input.send_keys file
```

Or you can easily locate this upload element using `name` locator instead as :-

```
upload_input = $driver.find_element(:name, "coupon_file")
upload_input.send_keys file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Saurabh, you are absolutely right!!!(Also thank you for editing my question and making it look nice cause I'm new to stackoveroflow)