# How to handle handle file_field_tag with Cucumber in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, import, cucumber, spreadsheet

I am currently working on a page for an application that allows a user to select an Excel spreadsheet using a file_field_tag within a form_tag. The project is written with Ruby on Rails. We are doing BDD for the project and I am trying to think of the best way to go about writing the Cucumber test to handle the selecting of a file for the page.

Is it possible to have Cucumber test this functionality? If so, how do I go about this?

Comment: _Cucumber_ does not, It doesn't do any web/browser stuff itself, which you use other tools for such as RestClient, Mechnize, Selenium, Capybara, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access hidden file upload field with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143727/how-to-access-hidden-file-upload-field-with-selenium-webdriver)